# Calling xsl:param via the input xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am transforming XML into HTML using XSLT. My goal is to automate the creation of repetitive HTML by providing key information through an XML input.

So, I am creating this kind of XML documents to store the strings outputed to the final HTML:

```
<animals>
    <animal id="dog">
        Our best friend 
    </animal>
    <animal id="cat">
        King of the internet
    </animal>
    <animal id="sheep">
        Baaaaaah
    </animal>
</animals>
```

And I handle those strings through xls:params like this:

```
<xsl:param name="dog" select="/animals/animal[@id='dog']"/>
<xsl:param name="cat" select="/animals/animal[@id='cat']"/>
<xsl:param name="sheep" select="/animals/animal[@id='sheep']"/>
```

So that I can use those strings adding this kind of snippet to my stylesheet:

```
<ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$dog"/></li>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$cat"/></li>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$sheep"/></li>
</ul>
```

I want the user to be able to call strings through the input xml by adding the right tag into it. So if the input xml is something like this:

```
<input_xml>
    <animals>
        <cat/>
        <dog/>
    </animals>
</input_xml>
```

the output will be

```
<ul>
    <li>King of the internet</li>
    <li>Our best friend</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to automate the creation of such a list by looping through the tags like:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="/input_xml/animals">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="${tag name}"/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

but I don't know how to grab hold of the input xml tag name in the `select="${tag name}"`. I tried using `<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>`, but you cannot nest `xsl:value-of`

Comment: Do you have two input documents? Do you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using XSLT 2.0. 
I have some predefined xml files to store the repetitive information (animals) and refer to them using `<xsl:variable name="animals" select="document(animals.xml')"/>`, so that I can grab this info using `<xsl:param name="dog" select="$animals/animal[@id='dog']"/>`. The non repetitive information is provided by the input xml file. The whole thing works in a very similar way to the solution proposed by @zx485

Comment: @GabrielWarken: I'm glad that I may have approximated your desired answer pretty close. But what does your desired answer look like? An edit to your question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot handle the resulting strings with

```
<ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$dog"/></li>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$cat"/></li>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="$sheep"/></li>
</ul>
```

because this would always create an empty `<li>` tag if some variable would not be present.

A better solution would be using your first XML file, call it `animals.xml`...

```
<animals>
    <animal id="dog">
        Our best friend 
    </animal>
    <animal id="cat">
        King of the internet
    </animal>
    <animal id="sheep">
        Baaaaaah
    </animal>
</animals>
```

...and your second XML file, call it `input.xml`...

```
<input_xml>
    <animals>
        <cat/>
        <dog/>
    </animals>
</input_xml>
```

to combine them with the following XSLT which creates a variable referring to the first XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document('animals.xml')" />

  <xsl:template match="/input_xml"> 
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="animals/*[name() = $doc2/animals/animal/@id]">
        <xsl:variable name="animalName" select="name()" />
        <li><xsl:value-of select="$doc2/animals/animal[@id=$animalName]"/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this combination/transformation is

```
<ul>
    <li>
        King of the internet
    </li>
    <li>
        Our best friend 
    </li>    
</ul>
```

This solution combines both input files into one output file. The `input.xml` can be selected in the XSLT processor's parameters.

Comment: Since I can't make a `<xsl:for-each>` loop like the one in the original question work, that is exactly what I've been doing. I wanted to use a loop in this situation to avoid having to create a small template for every single param, since the final stylesheet will have the whole animal kingdom worth of params

Comment: @GabrielWarken: I changed my answer. I hope this will fit your needs more appropriately. It is as simple as it gets.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: I'd just like to add that I made a small change to the final solution. I now have some xsl:param variations, so the paramaters are no longer only `$dog`, but `$dogName` or `$dogDescrip`, etc. I am able make use of a `<dog>` tag from `input.xml` using your solution but declaring the xsl:variable `$animalName` as `<xsl:variable name="animalName" select="concat(name(.), 'Name')" />`

Answer (score 0):

As you use XSLT 2.0, you can define a key

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="animals/animal" use="@id"/>
```

and then use

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="/input_xml/animals/*">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="key('id', name(), $animals)"/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```